# Port Forwarding Port 80 to PS4 - what about other devices on port 80

Tags: ports, port-forwarding

I would like to forward several ports, including port 80, to my husband's PS4 for gaming purposes. On our network I know that there are a few other devices using port 80, notably a nanny-cam. These other devices are ONLY used locally and I do not wish for them to be accessible to the internet.

Presumably, forwarding port 80 to the PS4 will direct all traffic there and will not expose the other devices to nefarious bots looking to access them. Is this correct?

In case it is relevant, we are in a very rural setting, so physical access to our network by a ne'er-do-well is highly unlikely. Our initial router is one provided by our ISP, which is then hard-wired to a second router set in bridge mode. All devices on our network operate off the second router.

Comment: Ask in [NetworkEngineering.se]

Comment: @defalt Network Engineering doesn't touch consumer networks or application level stuff.

Comment: This isn't about information security. If you don't wish to expose port 80 of one internal device, just don't forward that port. Look on your router, UPnP is probably enabled.

Comment: The only service that will be exposed by this action would be on the PS4.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't seems to be security related, I will try to give you an answer. It might get transferred to another part of Stack Exchange.

> Presumably, forwarding port 80 to the PS4 will direct all traffic
>   there and will not expose the other devices to nefarious bots looking
>   to access them. Is this correct?

Yes, this is correct. However, port forwarding needs to be done on the ISP's router. Additionally, you might want to consider enabling uPNP and select NAT type 1 or NAT type 2 on the Playstation 4.

1. Go to "Settings"
2. Go to "Network"
3. Go to "Test internet connection"

In the results, it should show what NAT type you're using. When using uPNP you might not even need to forward ports in order for the Playstation 4 to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the consideration and I apologize for the miscategorization. Your response is very helpful and appreciated. The PS4 is currently showing NAT Type 3 and has been since we switched ISPs and got this router. uPNP is enabled on the personal router and not available on the ISP router, so I think I'll need to proceed with the port forwarding. I very much appreciate your consideration and thoughtful response.

Comment: No need to apologize , it was just meant to inform you. As far as what I've seen regarding the Playstation 4 and its NAT types, type 3 is the least favorite option from what I read in the past. I think in your case type 2 would be the preferred option. You could (if possible) add a port forwarding rule in the ISP router to the IP address of the Playstation 4. I recommend having a static IP address for the console which should be excluded from any DHCP range(s). From a security point of view this is not the best option as I am unaware how secure the HTTP server of the console is.